# How to make C library for ffi during `gem install`

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ffi

Recently I wrote a gem using [ffi](https://github.com/ffi/ffi). With this help, the ruby code can call the C extensions with a dynamic library, which I compile all C extensions into.

My gem structure is like this:

```
.
├── ext
│   ├── common.c
│   ├── common.h
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── ...
├── Gemfile
├── lib
│   ├── ...
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── ...
├── Rakefile
├── README.md
└── test
```

What I plan to do is running `make` in `./ext`, then everything goes ok.

But, the problem occurs. If other users install my gem with `gem install`, how to make C library for themselves?

Is any one willing to offer me a help? Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take a look at [ffi-compiler](https://github.com/ffi/ffi-compiler). There's an example on the gem's page:

### Example

Directory layout

```
lib
  |- example
      |- example.rb

ext
  |- example.c
  |- Rakefile

example.gemspec
```

lib/example/example.rb

```
require 'ffi'
require 'ffi-compiler/loader'

module Example
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib FFI::Compiler::Loader.find('example')

  # example function which takes no parameters and returns long
  attach_function :example, [], :long
end
```

ext/example.c

```
long
example(void)
{
    return 0xdeadbeef;
}
```

ext/Rakefile

```
require 'ffi-compiler/compile_task'

FFI::Compiler::CompileTask.new('example') do |c|
  c.have_header?('stdio.h', '/usr/local/include')
  c.have_func?('puts')
  c.have_library?('z')
end
```

example.gemspec

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.extensions << 'ext/Rakefile'
  s.name = 'example'
  s.version = '0.0.1'
  s.email = 'ffi-example'
  s.files = %w(example.gemspec) + Dir.glob("{lib,spec,ext}/**/*")
  s.add_dependency 'rake'
  s.add_dependency 'ffi-compiler'
end
```

Build gem and install it

```
gem build example.gemspec && gem install example-0.0.1.gem
Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: example
  Version: 0.0.1
  File: example-0.0.1.gem
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed example-0.0.1
```

Test it

```
$ irb
2.0.0dev :001 > require 'example/example'
 => true 
2.0.0dev :002 > puts "Example.example=#{Example.example.to_s(16)}"
Example.example=deadbeef
 => nil
```

2. You can run `make` command during gem installation this way:

   - add   `spec.extensions << 'ext/mkrf_conf.rb'` to your gemspec.
   - create `ext/mkrf_conf.rb` file:

   task :default { `make` }

   - enjoy!

Comment: `ffi-compiler` has not been updated for long and is lack of documents...Anyway, thank you for your answer.